# google spreadsheet API v4 - Find value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can i search a google spreadsheet using new api v4.

In the api docs i found [find/replace](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest), but it can't find cells, it only replaces cells. So is there any method to find a value in a google spreadsheet other than brute-force method of fetching all data and searching in it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a little bit of a kludge, but I create a cell using the API with this formula to search a specified column in a sheet:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("SEARCHSTRING",A1:A999),2)
```

This does mean I have to make three different calls (write, read, and clear) and it only works on a single column or row, but I find it useful for large spreadsheets.

Comment: And if you want just a row, you can try this: =ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("SEARCHSTRING",A:A,0),1)))