# google sheets api v4 update row where id equals value

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have in column ***A*** (ID) for each row an ID.
Now I want to update a row where the ID from column A equals my ID in my code.
In the old v3 version ([+ a wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)) I could just easy search the row with this code and row.save() it:

```
var row = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
    offset: 1,
    query: 'id = ' + user.id
});
```

But I cant find something like that for v4. the only thig I found was [this Answere from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987255/11825017) with an work around for this but that means that I need to write a cell, read the value of that cell, delete the cell and then read the row I actually wanted with the value from that cell and then overwrite the row with the updated data.

Is there currently a easier way to do that?

Comment: I cannot understand about `(+ a wrapper)`. Can you provide more information of your script?

Comment: I was using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) but this is build ontop of v3.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, even when Sheets API v4 is used, the search and put of values cannot be done by one API call. At least, 2 API calls are required for retrieving and putting values. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: if its just two call (read and write/update) that would be fine. I just want to know if there is another methode exept with this "create a cell with a formal to get a position" workaround (The workaround needs 5 calls total)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. In your case, how about this flow? 1. Retrieve values with spreadsheets.values.get and spreadsheets.values.batchGet. One API is used here. 2. Retrieve the required values and index from the retrieved values using a script. 3. Put the values with spreadsheets.values.update and spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate as update. One API is used here. You can use Sheets API by googleapis of Node.js. By this, I think that your goal can be achieved. If you need a sample script, feel free to tell us.

Comment: When you need a sample script, when a sample Spreadsheet is provided, it will help to prepare it.

Comment: So you mean that I read all rows and filter via script. And then Update only the updated row? And thank for your help

Comment: I would like to confirm about your goal. Can I ask you about `filter via script`? You want to retrieve values from Spreadsheet, and the values are updated by a script. Then, you want to put the updated values as the overwrite. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I've now understood that I read all rows and then in the array I get I search the row where column 'A' corresponds to my ID and then edit the row. And due to the index I know where to save/update/overwrite this line in another API call. right?

Comment: I think that your replying is correct.

Comment: @Tanaike Can you take a look at my answere? That's how I handle the updates now.

Comment: I think that the script is good. I'm glad your issue was resolved. So I would like to upvote it. If your issue was resolved, please accept it. It will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I currently have this solution.

If someone knows a shorter or better way to do it please post an answere here too.

```
function UpdateRow() {
//Get all Rows
Sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    range: "Tabellenblatt1!A:J"
}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        const numRows = result.data.values ? result.data.values.length : 0;
        console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
        source = result.data.values;
        //Filter all rows except the one where the first column (A) equals my id + creates a new entry with the old index at [0]
        const input = source.map(function (row, index) {
            row.unshift(index);
            return row;
        }).filter(function (iRow) {
                return iRow[1] === "438065329533353986";
            });
        var index = parseInt(input[0]) + 1; //Saves the old index
        input[0].shift(); //Removes the old index from the array

        input[0][2] = "TEST"; //Update the row with stuff

        let values = [
            input[0]
        ];
        const resource = {
            values
        };
        Sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
            spreadsheetId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            range: "Tabellenblatt1!A" + index + ":J" + index, //Saves the row at the old index from before
            valueInputOption: "RAW",
            resource : resource
        }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('%d cells updated.', result.data.updatedRows);
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Another way to do this would be to use the metadata to identify correct rows https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata

Answer (score 1):

My trick was to create a column with the row number. In this manner, each time a new row is added you must add to this cell the value '=row'

Second I use google visualization query to check the condition (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) .

Finally, I update datasheet based in the row where condition has been true.

My solution in PHP:

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-client/vendor/autoload.php';
$secret_file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/secret_file.json';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($secret_file_path);
$client->addScope(array(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY, Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS));

$access_token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()["access_token"];   

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);  
$gsheetId = '1VdXw5LrQDZYclimloMr1PfGjIRxjztiXVva1M0pXix';
$params = [
    'valueInputOption' => "USER_ENTERED"    // "RAW" See: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing
];
$range = 'Users!A:E';

$data = [['=ROW()', '=true', $c, $d, $e]];

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange ([
    'values' => $data
]);

$gid = '2089252628';

$sql = urlencode("select * where D='{$value}'");
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'.$gsheetId.'/gviz/tq?gid='.$gid.'&tqx=out:json&tq='.$sql.'&access_token='.$access_token;
$res = parseGV(file_get_contents($url));

if(empty($res)) {   // If it is a new endpoint then append new row
    $range = 'Users!A:E';
    $response['insert'] = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($gsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
}
else {  // If it exists the endpoint then update the row
    $range = 'Usuarios!A'.$res[0]["Row"].':E'.$res[0]["Row"];
    $response['insert'] = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($gsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
}

function parseGV($gv) {
    $response = substr($gv, strpos($gv, "\n") + 1);     // Delete first line
    $data = preg_replace('/google.visualization.Query.setResponse\(/', '', $response);
    $data = preg_replace('/\)\;/', '', $data);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $data_keys = $data->table->cols;
    $data_rows = $data->table->rows;
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($data_rows as $key => $row) {
        $a = array();
        foreach ($row->c as $k => $value) {
            if(isset($value->v)) {
                $a[$data_keys[$k]->label] = $value->v;  
            }
            else {
                $a[$data_keys[$k]->label] = null;
            }
        }
        $arr[] = $a;
    }
    return ($arr);
}
```