# Update specific row in google sheets based on ID value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a project for a Chrome Extension I am creating where it uses Google Sheets as a "database". I have the create and get part down. However, I am struggling with the update part.  Here is my code so far:

```html
      let init = {
        method: 'GET',
        async: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'contentType': 'json'
      };
      fetch(
        "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_ID}/values/All Escalations!A5:Z10000001",
        init)

        .then((data) => {
          
          return data.json();

          }).then ((completedata) => {
          const numRows = completedata.values ? completedata.values.length: 0
          console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved`)
         let source = completedata.values;
          const input = source.filter(function (row, index) {
            row.unshift(index);
            return row;
        }).filter(function (iRow) {
                return iRow[1] === arcaseiddis;
            });
            var index = (input[1]) ; //Saves the old index
            let arjira2 = document.getElementById('jiracard').value
            let ardatesubmitteddis2 = document.getElementById('datesubmitted').value
            let arsubmittedbydis2 = document.getElementById('submittedbyaredit').value
            let arclientiddis2 = document.getElementById('clientidaredit').value
            let arcasenumberdis2 = document.getElementById('casenoaredit').value
            let arnotesdis2 = document.getElementById('notesaredit').value
            let arstatusdis2 = document.getElementById('statusaredit').value
            let arissuedis2 = document.getElementById('casedesaredit').value
            let arassignedtodis2 = document.getElementById('assignedtoaredit').value
            let datearcompleted = document.getElementById('datecompletearedit').value

            let arcaseiddis2 = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id
        input[0]= arcaseiddis2; //Update the row with stuff
        input[1] = arcasenumberdis2;
        input[2]= arjira2;
        input[3]= arstatusdis2;
        input[4]= arissuedis2;
        input[5]= arclientiddis2;
        input[6]= ardatesubmitteddis2;
        input[7]= arsubmittedbydis2;
        input[8]= arassignedtodis2
        input[9]= datearcompleted
        input[10]= arnotesdis2

        let values = [

          
        [
        input[0],
        input[1],
        input[2],
        input[3],
        input[4],
        input[5],
        input[6],
        input[7],
        input[8],
        input[9],
        input[10]
      ]
            
        ];

        
        const resource = {
            values
        };

        console.log(values)
```

I am able to console.log this out and it actually shows the updates I put in. However, when I run the update function it gives the following error:

```html
{range: "All Escalations!Aundefined:Jundefined", values: {values: [,…]}}
range
: 
"All Escalations!Aundefined:Jundefined"
values
: 
{values: [,…]}
values
: 
[,…]
0
: 
["82389566743686", "4306203", "None", "SUBMITTED", "Testing", "Client", "2/8/2023", "John SMith",…]
0
: 
"82389566743686"
1
: 
"4306203"
2
: 
"None"
3
: 
"SUBMITTED"
4
: 
"Testing"
5
: 
"Client"
6
: 
"2/8/2023"
7
: 
"John Smith"
8
: 
"Carey Jones"
9
: 
""
10
: 
"No Notes Yet"
```

This is the update function I am running:

```html
        var payload = {
          
          "range": "All Escalations!A" + index + ":J" + index,
          "values": resource
        }
    let init = {
      method: 'PUT',
      async: true,
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      
    };
    fetch(
        "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SpreadsheetID}/values/All Escalations/?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED",
        init)
   
          })
```

The code I've used so far is mainly coming from this article: [google sheets api v4 update row where id equals value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289676/google-sheets-api-v4-update-row-where-id-equals-value)

Because this is a Chrome Extension I can't connect to the api via the URL like we used to in MV2. So I do it via the "fetch" method and it works for the get part.  From looking over the above article, it looks like the person does the "get" to get that specific row. Then updates the specific row based on the ID.  I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I did get this to update the sheet. However, it randomly picks a row in the spreadsheet to update rather than the row that that needs to be updated.

It seems to be something in the get call I am making. The odd thing is it does console.log that row with no issue. It's just when I run the update call it randomly picks a row in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

With some tinkering around I found the answer:

I credit Take A Minute with getting me in the right direction with his snippet. [google sheets api v4 update row where id equals value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289676/google-sheets-api-v4-update-row-where-id-equals-value). I am just starting out at this so any input on how to make this more efficient is welcome.

```
  function updatearescalation(){
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, getToken);

function getToken(token) { // this seems to be the best way to get the token to be able to make these requests. 
  
  let initdarread = {
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'contentType': 'json'
  };
  fetch(
    "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1uXGfr5OvJjW2Pb9YhkbLHED3cQcJI5YsvJKLedAHRKY/values/All Escalations!A5:Z10000001",
    initdarread)
    
    .then((data) => {
      
      return data.json();

      }).then ((completedata) => {
        
      const numRows = completedata.data ? completedata.data.length: 0
      console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved`)
       source = completedata.values;
      const input = source.filter(function (row, index) {// when I use the source.map it returns a random row instead of the specific row I want. 
        row.unshift(index);
        return row;
        
    }).filter(function (iRow) {
            return iRow[1] === arcaseiddis;
        });
        var index = parseInt(input[0]) + 5; //Saves the old index The +5 indicates where the actual data starts. This is important. 
        input[0].shift(); //According to post previously mentioned this removes the old index. 
                    
   input[0] // This is where you update the rows with what you want. 
    

    let values = [
  
    input[0], // This is where all the values you want updated go. 
              
    ];
   
    const resource = {
        values
    };
    
var payload = {
      
      "range": "All Escalations!A" + index + ":K" ,
      "values": resource
    }
  let  range = "All Escalations!A" + index + ":K"
let initarupdate = {
  method: 'PUT',
  async: true,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  
};
fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1uXGfr5OvJjW2Pb9YhkbLHED3cQcJI5YsvJKLedAHRKY/values/${range}/?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
    initarupdate)

      }) // I used a literal here to be able to use the Range I put in the payload. 

       

}
```

}